# send and count different get vars to database php , jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have a jquery script which send a get var with id to a page named ajaxprocess,php each time a specific element is clicked . i have 20 elements.

the idea is create a temp table with 3 field , each time element is clicked it stores its value in field 1 , second in field 2 and third in  field 3 and stop , i just want to get 3 ids stored .

here is the code.
the `jQuery('#test').text(data);` is to test if vars were sent.
the elements are all like this : `<div class="element" id ="the id to retrieve"></div>` .

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".element").click(function () {
        var path =  $(this).attr('id') ;
        $.get('ajaxprocess.php', {Path: path}, function(data){
            $('#test').text(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

i tried to make a count but no success.

Comment: Why do you use `jQuery` instead of `$` in the inner functions? There's **no** good reason for this.

Comment: What is it exactly you are stuck with?

Comment: yes , it was while testing i removed it now and its working the same .

Comment: thanks for the response. well i get perfect the first value sent when i click on an element . i want to grab this value on the database. then when i click on the second element i want to grab this second value to a second field

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understanding where the problem lies.  What does your PHP code look like?  Have you tried var_dump()-ing or something in PHP to see if the problem lies in your PHP code?

Comment: thanks for the response , i got it working , i had problem with inserting values if the previous was full.